# Create a new folder on HSDS server with Python

Tags: python, hdf5, hdf

How is a new folder created using h5pyd module in Python?

For example, I have the domain `/home/user/` and I want to create a folder `/home/user/data1/`.

From the command line I can use the following command:

```bash
hstouch /home/user/data1/
```

What is the equivalent in h5pyd?

See below for a simplified example of what I am trying to do.

```py
import h5pyd
import numpy as np
with h5pyd.File("/home/user/data1/myfile.h5", "w") as f:
    dset = f.create_dataset("mydataset", (100,), dtype='i')
```

However, because `/home/user/data1/` does not exist, I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You would just do:

```html
h5pyd.Folder("/home/user/data1/", mode="w')
```

There's a test case for this at:
[https://github.com/HDFGroup/h5pyd/blob/master/test/hl/test_folder.py#L178](https://h5pyd.Folder(%22/home/user/data1/%22,%20mode=%22w%27))